# How do determine the arrow form in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

I plotted following image:
[image]
Using this code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{bondgraph}                                          %Draw bondgraphs         
\usetikzlibrary[petri]                      % Petri nets

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
        \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=-1.1,thin,>=stealth, every transition/.style={fill,minimum width=1mm,minimum height=3.5mm}, every place/.style={draw,thick,minimum size=6mm}]
    \node[place,tokens=0,label=above:$p_G$] (pG) {};
    \node[transition,right=of pG,label=below:$t_{GY}$] (t1) {}
        edge[pre] (pG);
    \node[place,right=of t1,tokens=0,label=above:$p_Y$] (pY) {};
        %edge[pre] (t1);
    \node[transition,right=of pY,label=below:$t_{YR}$] (t2) {};
    \node[place,right=of t2,tokens=1,label=above:$p_R$] (pR) {};
    \node[transition,above=of pY,label=below:$t_{RG}$] (t3) {};
    \draw [->] (t1) -- (pY);
    \draw [->] (pY) -- (t2);
    \draw [->] (t2) -- (pR);
    \draw [->] (pR) to [out=315,in=0] (t3);
    \draw [->] (t3) to [out=180,in=135] (pG);
    %\draw [->] (t3) to [out=0,in=180,bend left] (pG);
    \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{Petri net model for traffic lights}
        \label{fig:task1pet1}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

How can I change the form of the arrow going from `t_{RG}` to `p_G` such that it is a mirrored version of the arrow from `p_R` to `t_{RG}`?

Comment: Change `\draw [->] (t3) to [out=180,in=135] (pG);` to `\draw [<-] (pG) to [out=225,in=180] (t3);`

Comment: This works but I do not see why the original one does not work.          `\draw [->] (t3) to [out=180,in=135] (pG);` seems more natural to me, why it does not work?

Comment: If you understand how `\draw [->] (pR) to [out=315,in=0] (t3);` works you'll understand why `\draw [->] (t3) to [out=180,in=135] (pG);` doesn't. `out=315` means the line will go out from `origin node` with a `315` angle. Therefore looking how line between `pR` and `t3` goes out, you can deduce that these 315 degrees are counted clock wise and not anti clock wise as usual. Then you can use my solution or can change `in=135` for `in=225` in your code.

Comment: In case you are interested, angles are clock wise because you use option `yscale=-1.1` (negative).

Comment: @Ignasi Would you like to write an answer?

Comment: @Ignasi an answer?

Comment: @PaulGessler Thank you for remind me it. Although as you can see, now I think my comment was not a complete correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following Paul's and Torbjørn's suggestion I've tried to convert my previous comments into  a complete answer. And doing it, I've found that although my solution worked it did it by chance.

My previous solution was changing `\draw [->] (t3) to [out=180,in=135] (pG);` with 
`\draw [<-] (pG) to [out=225,in=180] (t3);`.

This produced the expected result:

[image]

Now I think that MWijnand has found a wrong behavior in `to path` library when `{x|y}scale` has negative values, so here is a [`follow up question`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/224196/problem-with-in-to-path-angle-when-negative-scale-factor-are-applied) to confirm it.

Comment: Did you mean to upload an image? I see the placeholder but there is no link source in the post. :-)