# Problem with `in` (to path) angle when negative scale factor are applied

Tags: tikz-pgf

Trying to convert a coment into a complete answer for [How do determine the arrow form in Tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/178534/how-do-determine-the-arrow-form-in-tikz/224193#224193) I think that my solution there worked by chance and that MWijnand  found a wrong behavior in `to path` library when `{x|y}scale` has negative values.

Take a look at this example:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{bondgraph}          
\usetikzlibrary[petri] 

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thin,>=stealth, every place/.style={draw,thick,minimum size=6mm}]
    \node[place] (pG) {$p_G$};
    \node[place,right=3cm of pG] (pR) {$p_R$};
    \draw[->] (pR) to [out=150, in=30] (pG);
    \begin{scope}[yscale=-1]
    \draw[->,blue] (pR) to [out=150, in=30] (pG);
    \end{scope} 
    \begin{scope}[xscale=-1]
    \draw[->,red] (pR) to [out=150, in=30] (pG);
    \end{scope} 
    \begin{scope}[scale=-1]
    \draw[->,green] (pR) to [out=150, in=30] (pG);
    \end{scope} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and its strange result.

[image]

What I would expect was that `pR.center` was the paths origin and `pG.center` was the path end. The path would have a `out` angle affected by `scale` factor and the drawn path would start on corresponding intersection point over `pR` border. This is what happens with `out` angle as you can see around `pR` node.

But this doesn't happen with `in` angle (`pG` node). `in` angle fixes final anchor at  `pG.30` and not at `pG.center` as expected. It also changes incidence angle for which scale factor is applied.

I think this is wrong and I'll fill a [bug report](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/bugs/348/). If I'm wrong or you have a better solution, please let us know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually how it is supposed to work. The `in` and `out` directions are calculated in the current coordinate system.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[thin,>=stealth, place/.style={circle, draw,thick,inner sep=1pt}]
    \node[place] (pG) at (-1.5,0) {.};
    \node[place] (pR) at (1.5,0) {.};

    \draw[->] (pR) to [out=150, in=30] (pG);
    \draw (pR) -- +(150:1) (pG) -- +(30:1);

    \begin{scope}[yscale=-1,blue]
      \draw[->] (pR) to [out=150, in=30] (pG);
      \draw (pR) -- +(150:1) (pG) -- +(30:1);
    \end{scope}

    \begin{scope}[xscale=-1,red]
      \draw[->] (pR) to [out=150, in=30] (pG);
      \draw (pR) -- +(150:1) (pG) -- +(30:1);
    \end{scope}

    \begin{scope}[scale=-1,green]
      \draw[->] (pR) to [out=150, in=30] (pG);
      \draw (pR) -- +(150:1) (pG) -- +(30:1);
    \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But you can change this behaviour using `relative` style.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[thin,>=stealth, place/.style={circle, draw,thick,inner sep=1pt}]
    \node[place] (pG) at (-1.5,0) {.};
    \node[place] (pR) at (1.5,0) {.};

    \draw[->,relative] (pR) to [out=-30, in=-150] (pG);

    \begin{scope}[yscale=-1,blue]
      \draw[->,relative] (pR) to [out=-30, in=-150] (pG);
    \end{scope}

    \begin{scope}[xscale=-1,red]
      \draw[->,relative] (pR) to [out=-30, in=-150] (pG);
    \end{scope}

    \begin{scope}[scale=-1,green]
      \draw[->,relative] (pR) to [out=-30, in=-150] (pG);
    \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you fore `relative`, I didn't know it. But I don't agree with the correctness of first example. I can understand that all arriving angles are correct but I still think that the arriving target should be `pG.center` and now it's `pG.30`. Would you mind to include some comment explaining it?

Comment: Very often when mixing named coordinates and transformations, the TikZ guess of the anchor position is not correct. As the manual says "The exact rules are a bit complex, but the chosen point will usually be correct – and when it is not, Hagen can still specify the desired anchor by hand." ;)

Comment: You can check my answer here for more related info : http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/220317/9335

Comment: Thanks again. My conclusion is "use `relative` when `{x|y}scale=-1` is applied".

Comment: @Ignasi you are welcome. My personal taste : "use `relative` in general" ;)