# tikz problem using \draw ... to[out in] and mirroring/rotating

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-graphdrawing, draw, transformation

I have a graph in tikz, using `\draw ... to[out=...,in=...]` for arcs. It seems that mirroring and rotating does not work properly regarding the anchors of the to-node. Is this to be expected, or is it a bug? Is there a work-around?

[image: Example]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[circle,draw] (A) at (0,0) {A};
\node[circle,draw] (B) at (0,2) {B};
\draw (A) to[out=45,in=-45] (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\quad
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=-1]
\node[circle,draw] (A) at (0,0) {A};
\node[circle,draw] (B) at (0,2) {B};
\draw (A) to[out=45,in=-45] (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\quad
\begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=-1]
\node[circle,draw] (A) at (0,0) {A};
\node[circle,draw] (B) at (0,2) {B};
\draw (A) to[out=45,in=-45] (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\quad
\begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=90]
\node[circle,draw] (A) at (0,0) {A};
\node[circle,draw] (B) at (0,2) {B};
\draw (A) to[out=45,in=-45] (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\quad
\begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=180]
\node[circle,draw] (A) at (0,0) {A};
\node[circle,draw] (B) at (0,2) {B};
\draw (A) to[out=45,in=-45] (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: related? http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/224196/1952

Comment: Yes. The answer there (use relative angles instead of absolute ones) also solves my problem. When replacing the \draw lines with **\draw[relative] (A) to[out=-45,in=-135] (B);** everything works.

Comment: Though it still seems a bug to me that the anchor of A correctly transforms, as well as the angles on both sides, but not the anchor of B.